# Splitting RGB image into separate bands using Drone (DJI Phantom imagery)

Tags: remote-sensing, multi-band, rgb, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

Previously I have made marine habitat maps using multiband imagery and remote sensing techniques (e.g blue, green and red bands from satellite imagery).

I am now attempting the same process however using drone imagery (DJI Phantom 3 pro). Is it possible to obtain separate bands from the RGB images that are captured and if so how can I do this?

Comment: I don't know about your drone software but GDAL_Translate -b n http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html where n is the band you want will extract just one band to a separate raster. If you're not comfortable with commandline it can be invoked from QGIS (Raster::Translate).

Comment: @MichaelStimson, I would recommend adding this excellent comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is simple and the reverse process of layer stacking in Erdas Imagine. Just follow the steps. I am giving here the process one by one. :)

First open the stacked image in Erdas Imagine 2014. Go to Raster> Spetral>Layer Stack. 
In the Layer stack window, input the Stacked image. You can see the bands by clicking in the layer. The given file has 6 bands.

[image]

Second step: Select which band you want to separate and then click add. A directory will be displayed in the box, as shown by red box in the give picture.

[image]

Third Step: In the third step, go to output and save the image band in your preferred directory.

Thus you can separate all the bands repeating the step 2 and 3.[image]

Comment: You might want to elaborate on what the steps are. I understand your solution and think it's an effective one, but someone who hasn't done it before might not be able to infer the process from what you've provided.

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS, load the RGB image> Processing > ToolBox > Search "r.rgb".
(SAGA also has an algorithm in toolbox : split rgb band)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about your drone software but [GDAL_Translate](http://gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) -b n where n is the band you want will extract just one band to a separate raster, for example GDAL_Translate -of GTIFF -b 1 -b 3 -b 7 will create a 3 band raster with bands RED=1, GREEN=3, BLUE=7; GDAL_Translate -of GTIFF -b 3 will create a single band GeoTIFF with the contents from band 3.

If you're not comfortable with commandline it can be invoked from QGIS (Raster::Conversion::Translate) but I've found with the more recent versions of QGIS it difficult to edit the command line to insert the -b switches; there is [scripting syntax for Translate](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_conversion/translate.html) but I have not seen the band implicitly specified. You can copy/paste the string into a text editor from the GUI invoked by Translate and add your band specifier(s) manually and run in a GDAL shell window.

Answer (score -1):

You could use Raster Calculator in QGIS, you would be able to separate Red, Green and Blue bands individually.